# retrive all childs from N number of levels From Collection

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I am new with collections.
I have following Class

```
class ParantCategory {
    int id;
    String name;
    int pid;
    public ParantCategory(int id, String name, int pid) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pid = pid;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }
    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
}
```

And My main method class is as

```
public class HierachiDemo {
    static ArrayList<ParantCategory> al = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        al.add(new ParantCategory(1, "000", 0));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(2, "A1", 1));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(3, "B1", 1));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(4, "A11", 2));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(5, "A12", 2));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(6, "A13", 2));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(7, "B11", 3));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(8, "B12", 3));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(9, "B13", 3));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(10, "A111", 4));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(11, "A112", 4));
        al.add(new ParantCategory(12, "A113", 4));
        HierachiDemo h = new HierachiDemo();
        //function call here
    }
}
```

I have stored elements in arraylist.
Now my question is I need recursion function in that I will pass Name and it will give me all the children from n number of levels.
for example:
If I pass A1 as name, then it should return me all children like A11,A12,A13, and also if have subchild of A11,A12,A13 that should also display.
I need final result as A11,A12,A13,A111,A112,A113.

Comment: Are parent and child related through id and PID?

Comment: Why are you trying to represent a hierarchical structure in a list (flat) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy "brute force" solution would be:

```
List<ParantCategory> matches = new ArrayList<>();
for (ParantCatagory parant : al) {
  if (parant.getName().startsWith("A1")) {
    matches.add(al);
  }
}
```

You can also use Java8 streams with a simple filter instead.

Of course, that works for this simple string comparison. The key thing that **you** have to clarify is **what** such "child" relationships actually **mean** to you. In your example, you simply *told* us that you consider "A112" to be a *child* of "A1".

So, to address your comment: if you want to implement **real** hierarchical ordering, then you have to **express** that in code. Meaning: than you might have to create your own **tree** implementation; where you add your objects, and based **code** that you write, your tree orders elements in such "subclass" categories.

In other words: your current code makes simple assumptions on strings. If you need something more sophisticated; well, then **you** have to implement that. And the first step you have to take: clarify for yourself how such relationship need to be defined. That is nothing that we can be helping with!

In other words: right now, you only have objects of that Parant class. And those objects have absolutely **no** relationship between each other. If you want such relationships, you have to add means to your class to express them! For example by changing your class into a "Node" class; and a Node ... has methods to add/query **child** nodes!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But suppose childs of A1 is not start with "A1" then what should I do?

Comment: I updated my answer; but please understand that there isn't too much that we can really help with.

Comment: I think you used the name to create a parent child relationship, but OP is using the id/pid. The id/pid coincidentally corresponds to the names in this example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the current structure. You might make a method that does what you want. There are two things,

```
List<ParantCategory> getChildNodes(String name, int levels){
    List<ParantCategory> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ParantCategory head = null;

    //assuming there is only one ParantCategory with the supplied name.
    for(ParantCategory p: al){
        if(name.equals(al.getName())){
            head = al;
            break;
        }
    }

   //if we cannot find the name just use an empty list.
   if(head==null) return results;
   results.add(head);
   results.addAll(getChildren(head.getPid(), levels));
   return results;
```

}

We can make a recursive method for getting the children.

```
void getChildren(int pid, levels){

    if(levels==0) return Collection.emptyList();

    List<ParantCategory> results = al.stream().filter(
            p->p.getPid()==pid
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for(ParantCategory p: results){
        results.addAll(getChildren(p.getPid(), levels-1));
    }
    return results;
}
```